# Is $n^{n-2}$ the number of trees on $[n]$ where the sum of degrees of vertices is $2n-2$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I'm trying to count the number of trees on $[n]$ given that $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$ are positive integers with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i=2n-2$ and for $i\in[n]$ $\deg(i)=d_i$.

My thought process here is that since the sum of degrees is $2n-2$, we have $n-1$ edges. So the problem becomes counting the number of trees on $[n]$ with the condition that the graph has $n-1$ edges. In other words, just count the number of spanning trees on $[n]$. By Cayley's formula, I know that the number of spanning trees on $[n]$ is $n^{n-2}$.

A similar question has been asked on here before, so I'm sorry if this isn't how I'm supposed to ask my question, but an answer that looked different was given and I would really like to know why my logic here could be wrong.

link to the other question with a different answer: [Number of trees with vertex set $[n]$ and vertex $i$ with $deg(v_i)=d_i$ s.t. $\sum d_i = 2n-2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573770/number-of-trees-with-vertex-set-n-and-vertex-i-with-degv-i-d-i-s-t?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. Cayley's formula counts the total number of trees with $n$ labeled vertices without any restriction on the degree sequence of each tree. For this particular problem, we can use [Prufer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) to find the answer, much like in the proof of Cayley's formula.

Recall that we construct the Prufer code for a labeled tree (with labels on $[n]$) with the following algorithm: at step $i$ we remove the leaf with the smallest label and set the $i$-th element of our code to be equal to the label of this leaf's neighbor. The algorithm terminates when only 2 vertices remain (i.e. after $n-2$ steps). It can be shown that this procedure produces a bijection between labeled trees on $[n]$ and the set of sequences on $[n]$ with length $n-2$. Moreover, given a Prufer code $\mathcal{C}$ corresponding to a (unique) tree $T$ the degree of the vertex labeled $i$ in $T$ is equal to the number of times $i$ appears in $\mathcal{C}$ plus one. So, our graph theory problem can be reduced to a counting one, namely, we want to count the number of sequences with length $n-2$ such that $d_i-1$ of the elements are equal to $i$ for all $i=1,2,\dots,n$. This number is equal to the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$\binom{n-2}{d_1-1,d_2-1,\dots,d_n-1} = \frac{(n-2)!}{\prod_{i=1}^n (d_i-1)!}$$